# CodeFluent Force Update a Database Record

Tags: c#, asp.net, codefluent

I have the below simplified C# code to update a record with the ID of "1" with CodeFluent methods:

```
CFEObject anObject = new CFEObject();
anObject.ID = 1; //ID is the primary key, and an Identity Column
anObject.Name = "New Name";
anObject.Save();
```

The issue with the above code is it doesn't update the object with ID 1.
Instead, it gets the next ID and create a new record, rather then an edit of an existing record.

I realise that loading the CFE object by using "LoadById" method would solve the above issue, but I can't use that as I don't have the ID until later when the values are already set. So when I use "LoadById", it would erase my existing set properties.

How might I be able to force it to update the CFE record with the ID of "1" without using LoadById method?

Comment: If the property is identity, then only the db layer can set it. This is not really a CodeFluent issue. You can remove the identity behavior, or choose Guid as key type if you want to be able to have know the unique key before it's even persisted for the first time.

Comment: I'm not doing a set, it's an update of an existing record, that is already persisted. i.e. My intentions was not creating a new record with an ID of 1, but modifying an existing record with ID of 1.

Comment: I undestand that. I was talking about your "can't do a LoadById" objection.

Answer (score 1):

The `Save` method calls the generated stored procedure. You can check the code of that stored procedure to understand why it creates a new record instead of updating the existing one.

By default the optimistic concurrency is enabled. In this mode you need to set the `RowVersion` property before updating an instance. If the value is `null`, the stored procedure will create a new record.